# Permutation in descending order.

Tags: combinatorics, permutations

During a draw of lottery, tickets bearing numbers $1, 2, 3,......, 40$. $6 $ tickets are drawn out & then arranged in the descending order of their numbers. In how many ways, it is possible to have $4^{th}$ ticket
bearing number $25$.
If $4^{th}$ is $ 25$ then the $5^{th}$ and $6^{th} $ places can be filled with $\frac{23(23+1)}{2} $ ways . How can I find the arrangements of the first four ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

That's right for the last two. However, I'd like to offer a different perspective. For the first 3, we need to choose 3 numbers from $\{40,\dotsc,26\}$. Then arrange them. But there's only one way that they will be descending. Then chose 25. After, choose 2 from $\{24,\dotsc,1\}$. But there's only one way that will be in descending order. Thus, the number of ways to do this ism,
$$\binom{15}{3}\binom{1}{1}\binom{24}{2} = 125580.$$
In this manner, we avoid dividing directly.

Comment: You are backwards, too, and in addition you think the highest number is $45$ while OP said $40$.  You need only $2$ from $26-40$ and $3$ from $1-24$.

Comment: Umm I wrote 45 put I pulled from 15, that was just a typo. As for 2 from 26-40... I'm not so sure....

Comment: I'm not gonna lie, I'm not seeing what you're saying and I would like to reach an agreement.

Answer (score 1):

- Choose the first three numbers from $15$ possibilities. . . . . $C(15,3)$ ways.
- Choose the last two numbers from $24$ possibilities. . . . . $C(24,2)$ ways.
- Arrange in order. . . . . $1$ way.

Answer: $C(15,3)C(24,2)$.

Comment: Can you please explain the 'possibilities'. Your answer is correct.